# Regular expression (match function), javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, match

I think this is a very basic question, but I really can't understand the concept. I have the following regular expression:

```
var t = '11:59 am';
t.match(/^(\d+)/);
```

Now, according to my understanding when I print the value I should just get `11` since I am just checking for digits. However, I get `11,11`. I have to use 0th element to pick the required value like `t.match(/^(\d+)/)[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are using a [capture group, `()`,](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) around the digits. Try replacing this with:

```
t.match(/^\d+/);
```

Note: this will still return an array, because that's just what [`.match()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) does.

Comment: Thank you sam.I understand it now. I dint know about the capture group.

Comment: Glad I could help. Sorry that, as far as I know, there isn't a good JS regex method to just return a simple string instead of an array of data. [`/^\d+/.exec(t)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) will return `['11']` as well.

Answer (score 1):

`match()` [always returns an array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) if there are any matches.  Element `[0]` is the whole match, and element `[1]` is what is inside the first set of parentheses.